# Create collection from two other collections

Tags: java, generics, collections

In C# if I had 2 generic Collections

```
SthCollection<Sth>
```

and

```
SthElseCollection<SthElse>
```

I could create a third one like

```
SthAndSthElseCollection<Sth, SthElse>
```

(Where Sth and SthElse are Lists of some objects).

How could I "migrate" this to Java? Could I do this with enum or another collection type? I would appreciate a good link for such things. Thank you for your help

Comment: Is it a question about the generic type of the union collection, or are you simply asking how to create a colection containing the contents of two other collections? Do Sth and SthElse share a common superclass or interface other than Object?

Comment: creating a colection out of the contents of two other collections would be great for me. As far as Sth and SthElse is concerned, in what I was doing in C#, Sth was Interface and SthElse and abstract class. Now, as I want to use them, they share Object.

Answer (score 2):

org.apache.commons.collections.CollectionUtils has a union method which creates a Collection from 2 collections.

Here is the link:http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html

Answer (score 1):

If the only common supertype between the two types is `Object`, then use

```
List<Object> union = new ArrayList<Object>();
union.addAll(collectionOfSth);
union.addAll(collectionOfSthElse);
```

You can do the same with `Set` if what you want is a Set.

Note that this will create a copy, and not a view over the two collections. If what you want is a view of the union of two sets, then look at Guava [`Sets.union()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#union%28java.util.Set,%20java.util.Set%29), or [`Iterables.concat()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat%28java.lang.Iterable...%29).

Comment: I see...but what would be the difference if that list had -for example- two lists like `List<sthObject>` and `List<sthElseObject>`? `addAll` seems to work in that case, right?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Are you asking if it's possible to create a list of lists?

Comment: yes. Wouldn't it be the same as the example you showed me?

Comment: No. The example i give creates a list containing all the elements of the two collections. i.e. [a, b] + [c, d] becomes [a, b, c, d]. A list of lists would contain 2 elements: the first list and the second list, i.e. [[a, b], [c, d]]. Have you read the javadoc of the classes and methods used?

Comment: I read about union and it sais `public static java.util.Collection union(java.util.Collection a, java.util.Collection b)`. So I thought I could call union for two List collections. The second one `[[a, b], [c, d]]` could do also

Answer (score 0):

You could use Guava for this:

```
final Collection<T> col1  = ...;
final Collection<T> col2  = ...;
final Iterable<T> combined = Iterables.concat(col1, col12);
```

[http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat(java.lang.Iterable...)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat%28java.lang.Iterable...%29)